# An issuewith a slider and a a label

Tags: ios, slider, label

I'd appreciate if anyone could help.

I've created a slider and a label that changes it's text value when the user changes the slider. It's not working, for some reason.
Thoughts ?

I'm using xcode 6.1

Here's the code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *sliderLabel;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.sliderLabel.text = @"50";
}

- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender {
    [self.nameField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.numberField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    int progress = lroundf(sender.value);
    self.sliderLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", progress];
}

@end
```

Comment: have you bind method with slider?

Comment: Yes. Used the drag option - this is how the code at the bottom was created.

Comment: is the method `sliderChanged` called? did you try to set a breakpoint there?

Comment: @RonBaker Hope you have bind method with "value changed"

Comment: Chintu, that could be it. How do I check it ?

Comment: @RonBaker take outlet of UISlider same as UILabel. now in `viewDidLoad` add `[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];` and check now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take `UISlider` outlet and add selector as value changed in viewDidLoad like below.

```
IBOutlet UISlider *slider;
```

and to add selector in `viewDidLoad`

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```